# Checking the Class of an Instance Method in IRB

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I am new to ruby.

In the commandline within `Irb` I can check what class a method belongs to, for example: `to_s` (which belongs to the `String` class):

[image: to_s method... belongs to String Class]

However, when I do the same for the add method [(which belongs to the `ThreadGroup` class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/ThreadGroup.html)).. It does not tell me the class. I do not understand this.

[image: add method..belongs to ThreadGroup class]

Can anybody explain why this is? Thanks for any tips.

*Note: I have edited my `to_s` screenshot for clarification.*

Comment: Don't use screenshots unless you are displaying the result of a GUI your code generates. For this question you should use the actual text; copy and paste it into the question. That way, even that text can be searched for, and found, by others needing the same help. By doing so, you make Stack Overflow that much more useful to others.

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan .. I had not thought of it like that. Will do in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ThreadGroup#add`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/ThreadGroup.html#method-i-add) is an *instance method* of the class `ThreadGroup`,not an *instance*. You can call [`Object#class`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-class) on the instances of a class,but not on the methods. `Object` class don't have any method called `add`,thus you got a legitimate error.On the top level `self`,which is `main`,is an instance of `Object` class.

```
self.instance_of?(Object) # => true
self.respond_to?(:to_s) # => true
self.respond_to?(:add) # => false
```

The `to_s.class` works,because it actually is `self.to_s.class`.

```
to_s # => "main"
self.to_s # => "main"
to_s.class # => String
```

Comment: Ok, so it will generally only return the class if it belongs to the `Object` Class? I have test numerous methods from this class in the last minute and this seems to confirm what you say.

Comment: No, it will return the class if the method you are calling returns something. But in irb you can only call methods that exist in object. Or you call it on an instance of some object: `1.class #=> Fixnum`, `"foo".class #=> String`, `:foo.class #=> Symbol`, `"foo".to_i.class => Fixnum`...

Answer (score 4):

`to_s.class` does not return `String`, because it belongs to the `String` class. It returns `String` because `to_s` returns a `String`. If you call `to_s` in irb it returns `"main"`, what is a `String`.

You cannot call `add` in irb directly, because the `Main` object does not respond to it.